# XY model bessel function

Tags: statistical-mechanics

If

$$
Z = tr\left[ \Pi_{i=1}^N \int_0^{2\pi} d\theta_i \exp{(\beta J \cos{(\theta_i - \theta_{i+1})})}\right]
$$

Then why does the eigenvalue problem:

$$
\exp{(\beta J \cos{(\theta - \theta^\prime)})} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty I_n(\beta J)e^{in(\theta - \theta^\prime)} 
$$

where

$$
I_n(\beta J) = \int_0^{2\pi} \dfrac{d\phi}{2\pi} e^{\beta J \cos{\phi}}\cos{n\phi}?
$$

Comment: This is just a Fourier series.

Comment: I know that it's an inverse Fourier transform but I'm not seeing how to get the cos(n phi) term.

Answer (score 1):

We can write a function on the circle in a Fourier series as
\begin{align}
f(\theta) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_ne^{in\theta}.
\end{align}
The Fourier coefficients are
\begin{align}
c_n &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(\theta)e^{-in\theta}\,d\theta\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(\theta)\left(\cos n\theta - i \sin n\theta\right)\,d\theta
\end{align}
If $f$ is even, $f(-\theta) = f(\theta)$, then
\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi} f(\theta) \sin n\theta\,d\theta = 0.
\end{align}
(In case this isn't obvious, translate the integrand to make the limits symmetric about zero, then since $\sin$ is odd and $f$ is even, the integral vanishes.)
So
\begin{align}
c_n = \boxed{\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(\theta)\cos n \theta\,d\theta,}
\end{align}
which is just what you have with $f(\theta) = e^{\beta J \cos \theta}$.